# Pivot SQL Server with where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns, `ProductID`, `ProductAttribute` and `AttributeValue`.

I want to select records `AttributeValue` as a columns but only `where ProductID = 1`. I know that I have to use `MERGE`, but I don't know how.

And what function I have to use in Pivot? I know that I can `sum()` or `count()` but I want to only select records.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will receive a much better response if you include some sample data and the query you are using.

Comment: What is your input structure and what is your expected output?

Comment: Merge is used to insert & update rows in a table, so if you're only selecting the data, you don't need a merge.